# Executor: Wait for specific tasks to finish

Tags: java, multithreading

The server application I am running gets multiple requests for tasks which I want to handle using a task system.

Each task is represented as a `Runnable` that will demand `n` number of threads from a thread pool where `n` is smaller or equal to the thread pool size. The thread pool of course is necessary in order to *not* overload the CPU with too many threads.

However, some of those tasks can be multi threaded and some can not. That is why it might be necessary for one task to wait for all its specific threads to finish in order to merge the results from those threads for the final result.

If one uses multiple `Thread` instances one might join those like this:

```
try {
    // Wait for all threads to finish their tasks
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Finish job here ..
```

but I'd need something like this using `java.util.concurrent.Executor` or anything similar that works with a thread pool.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but it feels like you're using Executor on a wrong level of abstraction. If you have a task that requires *n* threads to run, I suggest you let that task create it's own thread pool, or break it down into smaller 1-thread tasks.

Comment: @aioobe you may end up with too many executors/pools which is not efficient

Comment: One could let each task do someSharedSemaphore.acquire(n) before starting its work.

Comment: You can check for Executors or ExecutorServices.

Comment: Arbi is right. I can not let a task run its own thread. It is the whole application that is limited to a specific number of threads. Imagine the client click 100 times on "run task". The server would execute to many threads causing each task to take forever. No, semaphore is too low-level

Comment: One could use the Observer pattern to inform when a Thread has finished its work, and do stuff when all of them have finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you will need something like this (but your architecture seems too complicated):

```
class MyTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // some work
    }
}
```

After that:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2000);
ArrayList<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();

futures.add(executorService.submit(new MyTask()));
futures.add(executorService.submit(new MyTask()));
futures.add(executorService.submit(new MyTask()));

for (Future future: futures) {
    try {
        future.get(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    } catch (Throwable cause) {
        // process cause
    }
}
```

Each future.get() will wait for task ending (max 100 seconds in this example).

Comment: I think the task should implements `Callable` not `Runnable` in order the future

Comment: @arbi Yes, if the result is important.

Comment: But if some tasks only require 1 thread, then it's pointless to wait for them to finish before launching the next.

Comment: @aioobe Yes, you are right. I suggested only idea "how to wait".

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Didn't know that this is called `Future`. What an odd name for an object ..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ExecutorService` along with a `CyclicBarrier` for each task as follows:

```
public class ThreadedTask implements Runnable {
    CyclicBarrier barrier;
    public ThreadedTask(CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        this.barrier = barrier;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
        barrier.await();
    }
}
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(pool_size);
...
CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(n+1);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    // launch all tasks
    executor.submit(new ThreadedTask(barrier));
}
// waits for the tasks to finish or timeout
barrier.await(seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: This does not seem like what I need. I don't want to wait for all threads. I want to wait for a bundle of threads that were executed by a specific task. Your answer seems to wait for all tasks ever executed.

Comment: not really, the part after the ... is the body of a task (I suppose in `run()` as your tasks implements `Runnable`). It's just an alternative  in case you want to use the powerful barrier concept.

Comment: Okay, now I get it! This is also a valid solution for my problem but I'll go for the other one. +1 anyway :)